# finding the closest value in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, sorting

I'm trying to take a value from a list and find the closest value from another list, and sort it so it's the same.. I'm not good at explaining..

here's my code:

```
list1 = [[111, 111], [222, 222], [333, 333]]
list2 = [[223, 223], [112, 112], [334, 334]]
#I need to find the closest value, and put list 2 in same order as list1
#i Want newlist to be [[[112, 112], [223, 223], [334, 334]]
newList = []
```

What should i do / look up to do this? I've tried to google, but just can't find anything relevant

edit:

```
if list1 = [[1, 1], [2, 2]] and list2 = [[2, 2], [100, 100]]

newlist would be [[2,2], [100, 100]]

if list1 = [[2, 2], [1, 1]] and list2 = [[2, 2], [100, 100]]

newlist would be [[100, 100], [2, 2]]
```

another edit: idk if it matters, but the lists are coordinates.

Comment: `list(map(sorted,list2))` or `[sorted(lst) for lst in list2]`?

Comment: One question: Suppose `list1 = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]` and `list2 = [[2, 2], [100, 100]]`. What would be the expected output for that? `[[2, 2], [2, 2]]`, or `[[2, 2], [100, 100]]`? Add this to your question please.

Comment: What if `list1 = [[1, 4], [2, 3]]` and `list2 = [[-1, -4], [-2, -3]]`?

Comment: it won't go negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sort  first list indices base on the list values and use them to rearange the second list:

```
list1 = [[222, 222], [111, 111], [333, 333]]
list2 = [[223, 223], [112, 112], [334, 334]]

idx = sorted(range(len(list1)), key=lambda i: list1[i])

newList = [list2[i] for i in idx]
newList
```

output:

```
[[112, 112], [223, 223], [334, 334]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the sort() function ? :

```
    list2 = [[223, 223], [112, 112], [334, 334]]

    list2.sort()
```

Output:

```
    list2 = [[112, 112], [223, 223], [334, 334]]
```

Comment: For the example they gave, yes this works. However, I doubt their question is as simple as this, since if `list1` was not sorted, the expected output wouldn't be sorted either

Comment: yes, I simplified the lists, theyre actually much longer, and not in order like these lists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the distance between tuples is measured by taking an absolute value of first element delta:

```
import numpy as np
[list2[i] for i in [np.argmin([np.abs(l2[0]-l1[0]) for l2 in list2]) for l1 in list1]]
```